# Java Applet code changes not reflected in browser

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

## Applet viewer issue

I have written code for applet application. The application changes hasn't reflected properly, while loading browser.

Even I am just commenting some part of applet coding.

I have following below steps to load application in browser (every change).

- Clear browser history
- Clear objects
- Clear java cache
  After doing this all, application working as expected.

Why it's not reflected immediately, if any changes happened?

Browser : IE 11.0.145
Java    : 1.8.0.66
We are loading dependency (jar) files using JNLP file format.

Kindly assist me on this.

Comment: I'm surprised you found a browser that works with applets. In any case, the browser gets the applet from where the page tells it to. Are you sure you copied your updated jar to that place (a server, or maybe a folder in the local machine)? You haven't supplied enough information in your question. At the very least you should [edit] your question and add the HTML embed code for the applet.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I hope I have added enough details.

Comment: I don't see any code.